# jQuery Image Gallery with Pictures Flying in and out

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been looking for a jQuery plugin that enables the pictures to fly in and out within a frame from all directions.

For example, a picture could fly in from the top corner, land within the frame and fly out of the bottom corner whilst another photo is flying into the frame from another angle.

Does anyone know of any plugins? Or how to create that myself? If I were to do that myself, I'm thinking it'd have to use HTML5 Canvas. I have looked at many different jQuery image slider plugins but all of them are fixed in their place.

If anyone knows a plugin or have any advice to give me, that would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try out exploring this link.They have some really nice collection of sliders.http://www.smartik.ws/2013/02/a-complete-list-of-responsive-jquery-sliders/

Comment: @NJInamdar Thanks for the link. I may have found what I needed in that list :)

Comment: Great,so you can choose to work with the one found accordingly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this one, but this one is only `fly in and out` from `left to right`. Check their scripts whether you can change direction/angle or not.

DEMO http://wowslider.com/jquery-slider-pinboard-fly-demo.html

Comment: I had a look at their code and it doesn't look like I can even find where to change direction / angle as you said. :S